# Content container shifting left/right - Stumped

Tags: html, css

Totally stumped. The 2 pages below - when you click between the 2 (I've put links for switching convenience) the content div jumps left or right depending.
Even odder is that if I reduce the number of items in section1.php down to just 4  ... it stops shifting. Anyone see what the deal is? I've tried all I know (limited css knowledge) but no joy...

https://www.ktbbconstitutionminute.com/section1.php
https://www.ktbbconstitutionminute.com/section2.php

using Foundation 5 with custom css file:
Custom css
https://www.ktbbconstitutionminute.com/css/constitution.css

Thanks!

Comment: Where do the divs jump? It is presenting fine for me.

Comment: For me the entire contents shift left/right. If you are on section 1 then click to section 2 the contents (from logo to footer) shifts right about 10 px. I'm surprised if it doesn't do that for you. I've checked with several PCs and browsers and it's consistent.

Comment: The pages look exactly the same for me too. Just a difference in text and image content

Comment: Probably cache.. looks ok on mobile

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'm an idiot it seems. The movement was due to the appearance of the scroll bar - on pages with enough content it will move to allow for the scroll bar. I should have known that - been a day I tell ya! That was the shifting I was seeing. doh!
Thanks!